# Chrome DevTools emulation devices presets

Tags: google-chrome, device-emulation

I've installed the new Beta version of Chrome to use the DevTools, my problem is that if I go in the Emulation tab, I don't modify nothing, my devices presets is locked at Google Nexus 4 and don't show me any list, the Emulate button is not clickable and I can't change any screen resolution.
What I have wrong or forgot?

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

1. **Uninstall Chrome** from your computer.
2. **Restart** your OS.
3. [Download Chrome **Canary**](http://www.google.com/intl/hu/chrome/browser/canary.html) and install it.
4. **Restart** your OS.
5. Visit the site you want to use in emulation.
6. Press F12 to **open Developer Tools**.
7. **Enable emulation** by clicking on the mobile icon (see the screenshot below).
8. Now you'll be able to change the emulated device.

[image]